# QGIS OpenLayers Plugin not showing

Tags: qgis-openlayers-plugin

I have the OpenLayers plugin on my computer (user/.../plugins), but it does not show when I open the plugins dialogue box. How do I get it to show in the plugins menu?

Comment: Look in QGIS Internet menu

Comment: Can you edit your question to say, how you obtained the plugin? and also what version of QGIS are you using?   Are you saying you installed the plugin not using the  Manage and Install Plugins option?

Comment: Try to reinstall openlayers plug-in. But you had better to change to QMS (Quick Map Services) plug-in.